# Unity and VS2017 ERROR

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have some problems with my vs2017.When I set VS2017 to be my code editor and when I open script VS load but there is no anywhere to type code.
and after some time monodevelop pop up and tells me that there is some error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: please specify what error

Comment: Yes. What your error?

Comment: When VS2017 open there is nowhere to write and monodevelop  pop-up and tells my that is something wrong.

Comment: @TomoBaster In the Visual studio your script should be in the asset folder in the solution explorer to the right did you try checking in there?

Answer (score 0):

On, the left side or right side (you have on right side) of the visual studio window, there must be the solution explorer with all the folders of your project.Just go to the folder of your scripts and double click the scripts to open them.

Comment: The error pop up and says "unrecognized guild format"

Comment: @TomoBaster I see you have solution explorer on the right side.Expand the assets folder there.If it don't work upgrade your unity version.There is also a tutorial for setting up unity with visual studio at unity's website.